# retrieve numbers from a string with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string which returns duration in the below format.

```
"152M0S" or "1H22M32S"
```

I need to extract hours, minutes and seconds from it as numbers.

I tried like the below with regex

```
video_duration.scan(/(\d+)?.(\d+)M(\d+)S/)
```

But it does not return as expected. Anyone has any idea where I am going wrong here.

Comment: You will also need to make the `H` part optional.

Comment: please describe how you want to use the resulting data. If you store your time strings in a proper format you can cast them directly to useful strings by using something like Date.format()

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Agree with @karthikmanchala.  For each of the two examples, show what you expect to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression: `/((?<h>\d+)H)?(?<m>\d+)M(?<s>\d+)S/`.

```
"1H22M32S".match(/((?<h>\d+)H)?(?<m>\d+)M(?<s>\d+)S/)
#=> #<MatchData "1H22M32S" h:"1" m:"22" s:"32">

"152M0S".match(/((?<h>\d+)H)?(?<m>\d+)M(?<s>\d+)S/)
#=> #<MatchData "152M0S" h:nil m:"152" s:"0">
```

Question mark after group makes it optional. To access data: `$~[:h]`.

Comment: if I need to extract 650.00 from "Rs. 650.00"?

Answer (score 2):

```
"1H22M0S".scan(/\d+/)
#=> ["1", "22", "0']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract numbers, you could do as :

```
"1H22M32S".match(/(?<hour>(\d+))H(?<min>(\d+))M(?<sec>(\d+))S/i).captures
# => ["1", "22", "32"]
"1H22M32S".match(/(?<hour>(\d+))H(?<min>(\d+))M(?<sec>(\d+))S/i)['min']
# => "22"
"1H22M32S".match(/(?<hour>(\d+))H(?<min>(\d+))M(?<sec>(\d+))S/i)['hour']
# => "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Me, I'd `hashify`:

```
def hashify(str)
  str.gsub(/\d+[HMS]/).with_object({}) { |s,h| h[s[-1]] = s.to_i }
end

hashify "152M0S"    #=> {"M"=>152, "S"=>0} 
hashify "1H22M32S"  #=> {"H"=>1, "M"=>22, "S"=>32} 
hashify "32S22M11H" #=> {"S"=>32, "M"=>22, "H"=>11} 
hashify "1S"        #=> {"S"=>1}
```